# Gradle: Add a resource in Plugin-Jar

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle plugin, that gets built as Jar and uploaded to a repository. Now I would like to move a configuration file into the src/main/resources folder of one plugin. But I can't get hold of the resource during project evaluation, I suspect it's because I am referencing it only in the buildscript { } block.

The project's buildscript essentially looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenRepo url: "http://..." }
    dependencies { classpath "gradle:loadtest-plugin:0.1.0" }
}

apply plugin: "loadtest-plugin"
```

Inside the loadtest-plugin.jar there is a src/main/resources/config.txt which I would like to access from inside the plugin, like this:

```
def config = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.txt").text
```

But I only get NullPointerExceptions. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` is an instance method, not a static method. (I'd expect Groovy to tell you that, in one way or another.) Try `getClass().classloader.getResourceAsStream()` or `buildscript.classLoader.getResourceAsStream()`.